# Incluir no email só as datas que estão para terminar

Tags: php, envio-de-email, comparação

Estou a preparar um email para enviar, mas só quero incluir no mesmo as datas que estão para terminar dentro de X dias.

**Actualmente tenho assim:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)) {
  $id = $row[0];
  $Nome = $row[1];
  $AlvaraValidade = $row[2];
  $AcidenteValidade = $row[3];
  $SeguroValidade = $row[4];
  $FinancasValidade = $row[5];
  $SocialValidade = $row[6];
  $RemuneracaoValidade = $row[7];
  $InstaladorValidade = $row[8];
  $MontadorValidade = $row[9];
  $MedicaValidade = $row[10];
  $ProjectistaValidade = $row[11];
  $GasValidade = $row[12];
  $RedesValidade = $row[13];
  $SoldadorValidade = $row[14];
  $MecanicoValidade = $row[15];
  $ClasSoldadorValidade = $row[16];
  $MaquinaValidade1 = $row[17];
  $MaquinaValidade2 = $row[18]; 
  $MaquinaValidade3 = $row[19]; 
  $MaquinaTopoValidade = $row[20];

  // ...
}
```

E depois no corpo do Email mostro os campos todos:

```
$PHPMailer->Body = "
<body>
  <p>
    <strong>Faltam 10 dias para terminar um ou mais documentos do </strong> $Nome
</body>
<body>
  <p><strong>As datas sao:</strong>
</body>
```

## Pergunta

Como posso verificar se a data de determinado campo está para terminar dentro de X dias para a incluir no email?

Comment: Editei a tua pergunta para explicar melhor o problema. Ao colocares uma pergunta, não assumas que quem a vai responder está a par das tuas restantes perguntas. Tenta clarificar o problema de forma isolada para viabilizar a pergunta e obteres respostas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazeres menção aos campos cuja data está para terminar, deverás comparar a data com uma data limite, no sentido de apurares se o campo deverá estar presente no email. Vamos assumir que a data limite são 10 dias para efeitos de clareza na resposta.

## Comparar as datas

A maneira mais simples será converter para Unix timestamp a data contida no campo e a data actual+10dias <sup>(data limite)</sup> com recurso à função [strtotime()](http://pt1.php.net/strtotime) enquanto fazemos a verificação:

```
//                         teu campo menor 
//                       que daqui a 10 dias
//                                ↑
//                                │
//        converter a data        │   converter a data de
//       do teu campo da BD       │    hoje mais 10 dias
//   ┌────────────┴────────────┐ ┌┴┐ ┌─────────┴─────────┐
if ( strtotime($row["teuCampo"])  <  strtotime("+10 days") ) {
  // fazer algo porque tem menos de 10 dias
}
```

A partir do exemplo em cima, podes realizar vários tipos de comparações para apurar se a tua data está como pretendes.

Desde que tenhas o código a executar dentro do `if(xx){ /* código aqui*/ }` já estás a criar a limitação que pretendes.

## Aplicando ao teu caso

No teu código, tens vários campos que parecem ser datas, por cada um que queiras verificar deverás proceder mediante o exemplo em baixo:

#### Comparação

Vamos comparar e criar o texto para o email apenas se a data está para terminar nos próximos 10 dias:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)) {

  // inicio do teu código

  /* COMPARAR */
  // iniciar variável a vazio
  $AlvaraValidadeHTML = '';

  // verificar se o valor de $row[2] é menor que daqui a 10 dias
  if ( strtotime($row[2])  <  strtotime("+10 days") ) {
    $AlvaraValidadeHTML = '<p>A validade do Alvará vai terminar no dia: '.$row[2].'</p>';
  }

  // resto do teu código
}
```

#### Anexar ao body do email

Construímos o corpo do email da forma que pretendemos e aplicamos as variáveis que contém a mensagem referente a cada documento no local pretendido.

Caso as mesmas contenham um valor resultante da comparação feita, vão aparecer, caso não, estão vazias e é como se não estivessem lá:

```
$PHPMailer->Body = "
<body>
  <p>
    <strong>
      Faltam 10 dias para terminar um ou mais documentos do $Nome
    </strong> 
  </p>
  ".$AlvaraValidadeHTML."
  ".$AcidenteValidadeHTML."
  ".$SeguroValidadeHTML."
</body>";
```

<sup>**Nota:** A formatação do HTML para o email que tens na pergunta está incorrecta, não deves ter mais que uma tag `body`.</sup>

---

## Optimização

Se vais efectivamente realizar muitas comparações de datas a expirar, o melhor será criares uma função para evitares andares sempre a repetir código:

```
/**
 * Está para expirar ?
 * 
 * Verifica se determinada data vai expirar até ao número de dias fornecido.
 * 
 * @param string $data      A data a verificar
 * @param integer $dias     Número de dias no futuro
 * 
 * @return $boolean         Verdadeiro ou falso
 */
function estaParaExpirar($data, $dias) {
    return ( strtotime($data)  <  strtotime("+".$dias." days") );
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)) {

    $id = $row[0];
    $Nome = $row[1];

    // se está para expirar dentro de 10 dias, recebe o texto, caso não fica vazio.
    $AlvaraValidade = estaParaExpirar($row[2], "10") ? '<p>A data do alvará vai expirar no dia '.$row[2].'</p>' : '';
    $AcidenteValidade = estaParaExpirar($row[3], "10") ? '<p>A data do acidente vai expirar no dia '.$row[3].'</p>' : '';
    $SeguroValidade = estaParaExpirar($row[4], "10") ? '<p>A data do seguro vai expirar no dia '.$row[4].'</p>' : '';
    // ... e continua nos restantes campos...

    // no corpo email é a mesma coisa que já te apresentei em cima.
```

<sup>**Nota:** A função está muito simples, criada para facilitar as coisas neste caso em particular, a mesma espera sempre receber uma data no primeiro parâmetro e um número (dias) no segundo parâmetro. Para utilizar a função em outros cenários, a mesma deveria confirmar se a data é mesmo uma data e não "lixo" e se o número de dias é mesmo um número.</sup>